# flatten files including foldername in filename

Tags: powershell

i'd like to flatten folder-structure and in one way include each parent directory name to filename. i've tried this, but get an error:

```
Missing ')' in method call
```

I quite don't see what's the problem

```
(ls -r -include *.ext) | % { mv -literal $_\3 $_\3.Name.Insert(0, [String]::Format("{0} - ", $_\3.Directory.Name))}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ls . -r *.ext -name | ?{!$_.PSIsContainer} | mi -dest {$_ -replace '\\','_'} -whatif
```

Or if on V3:

```
ls . -r *.ext -name -file | mi -dest {$_ -replace '\\','_'} -whatif
```

Remove the `-whatif` to actually perform the move.

Comment: It fails if the path contains square brackets [ ]. Seems have to use LiteralPath. Can you pls update with it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to flatten the folder structure and move all of the renamed files to the root directory?  For example:

```
$rootPath = 'C:\TempPath'
(ls $rootPath -r -include *.ext) | %{
    [string]$newFilename = $_.Name.Insert(0, [String]::Format("{0} - ", $_.Directory.Name))
    #write-host $newFilename
    mv -literal $_ "$rootPath$newFilename"
}
```

Comment: yes. i'd like to move all files with given extension existing in any subfolders to the root and change their filenames to filename including folder-structure to root.

your script throws the following error:

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\remove.ps1:3 char:42
+     [string]$newFilename = $_.Name.Insert( <<<< 0, [String]::Format("{0} - ", $_.Directory.Name))
Move-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'LiteralPath' because it is null.
At C:\remove.ps1:5 char:16
+     mv -literal  <<<< $_ "$rootPath$newFilename"